# what privileges required for executing a function in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic

what privileges required for executing a function in marklogic and i need to run below function with a new user

- xdmp:http-delete
- xdmp:eval
- xdmp:document-delete

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The privileges are different depending on the function. For those requiring a specific privilege. it is listed in the API doc for each function under "Required Privileges"

In the case of the delete, I do not believe there is a special execute privilege needed. However, you do need permissions on the document allowing you to delete the document.

For xdmp:eval, the privilege is:

> `http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdmp-eval`

This is listed on the API doc here: https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:eval

Comment: I am seeing page not found error message,, is there any other url or any trick to open this url.

Comment: the first one is not a URL.. its the name of the privilege.. Stack-exchange just makes it clickable.  the second one shows the docs.